# How to plot a figure of my purpose in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

in python, I would like to use:
`from pylab import *`
Then use `plot` provided in this module. However, the curves I plot were not what I want:
Say two lists:
`x = [1, 2, 3, 4]`
`y = [1.4, 5.6, 6, 3.5]`
and I am after a plot method that can plot the following chart:
Plot a line that joins the points: `(1, 0)` and `(1, 1.4)`
Plot a line that joins the points: `(2, 0)` and `(2, 5.6)`
Plot a line that joins the points: `(3, 0)` and `(3, 6)`
Plot a line that joins the points: `(4, 0)` and `(4, 3.5)`
  ...
i.e.: it should plot a spectra like graphs, such as `plot(x, type='h')` in `R`. I suppose the plot method I use just joins all the points by lines. So, for my purpose, which methods to choose please? thanks!!

Comment: I think you meant `import pylab` and then use the `pylab.plot` method.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooty, yes, I was doing the plot by pylab.plot, but it plots something not I want...that's why I am asking this question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you want just vertical lines? You could use `vlines(x, [0], y)`. See this [example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/vline_demo.html)

You could also have a look at this [page](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/screenshots.html) (screenshots) to help you select the right function.

Comment: I was just about to add that to my answer... Beat me to it!  If he just wants the vertical lines (and no marker at the end of them) then `vlines` is better than `stem`.  I think I'll delete mine to avoid confusion...

Comment: thank you !! that's what I want, I've searching for one hour now I got it, many thanks!~

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a bar chart? If so, just use the `bar` function:

```
bar(x, y)
```

Comment: No, not at all...if you could help to draw what I described, then you could see:) thank you!!